# BLOB to PDF download using Java and angular 5

Tags: java, angular, download, blob

I am trying to implement logic of download pdf from db on angular 5. I am facing issue in download file. File gets downloaded but throws error on opening -"Failed to load".

I have looked at so many blogs and question/answers but not able to find the mistake in my code.

```
In Database -> pdf file content saved as BLOB
```

Rest web service -> 
In below code pdfData is the data from BLOB type column, which is byte[] in java code here

```
@GetMapping("downloadReport/{reportId}")
public StreamingResponseBody downloadDocument(byte[] pdfData) {
        return outputStream -> {
        //This way working for sample
            /*try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:/pdfWithoutPassword.pdf")))) {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            }*/
        //This way not working when data fetched from Database
            try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfData)) {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        };
```

Angular 5 code

```
downloadReport(reportType: string, reportId: string) {
        let fileDownloadUrl = environment.apiUrl + "/downloadReport" + "/" + reportId;

        return this.httpClient
            .get(fileDownloadUrl, { observe: 'response', responseType: "blob"})
            .subscribe(response => this.saveFileToSystem(response.body)),
            error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
            () => console.info("OK");
    }

       saveFileToSystem(input: any) {
        const blob = new Blob([input], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        saveAs(blob, "testingpdf1.pdf");
    }
```

Looking for help in solving this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share stackblitz  so that we can edit ?

Comment: or response you are getting from server side

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534868/5695162)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Check everything and will reply. Also will edit the que as per comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

From your html page

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="generatePdf()"> YourPdf.pdf </a>
```

From your js file

```
generatePdf() {

this.yourService.generatePdf()
     .subscribe(pdf => {
     let mediaType = 'application/pdf';
     let blob = new 
     Blob([this.converterService.base64ToArrayBuffer(pdf.pdfByteArray)], { type: mediaType });
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
  }, err => {
    console.log('Pdf generated err: ', JSON.stringify(err));
  });
```

}

Your converter service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ConverterService {

base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
      return bytes;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Irshaad it worked along with your server side code. But with a small change in UI code. I have not used converter service on UI side. Here is my UI side code :

Comment: downloadt(reportId: string) {
         let fileDownloadUrl = environment.apiUrl + "orderHistory/test";
        return this.httpClient
            .get(fileDownloadUrl, { observe: 'response', responseType: "blob" })
            .subscribe(response => {this.saveFile(response.body)}, err => {
                console.log('err: ', JSON.stringify(err));
            });
    }
    saveFile(input: any) {
        const blob = new Blob([input], { type: 'octet/stream' });
        saveAs(blob, "a.pdf");
    }

Answer (score 1):

Here another way I did it you you can change :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateReport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generateReport(){

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    StringBuilder filename = new StringBuilder("MyPdfName").append(".pdf");

    byte[] bytes = pdfGeneratorService.generatePDF();
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename.toString());

    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```